# onImageLoad callback react js

Tags: reactjs, callback

Im using **react-image-gallery:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery

Im trying to set a useState variable on `onImageLoad`, but its not working.

the docs say to use a callback, and I tried using a callback but I don't think I was doing it correctly for functional components.

Could someone show me how to create the proper callback to get the `onImageLoad` prop?

Docs say..... `onImageLoad: Function, callback(event)`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

const Job = (props) => {

const {job} = props;  
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);
const [showImages, setShowImages] = useState(false);


useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoad() {

      try {
        const downloadedImage = await getImage(job.jobId);
        setImage(downloadedImage);
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e);
      }
    }

    onLoad();
  }, []);


return (
       {showImages ? (

         <div style={{width: "95%"}}>
          <ImageGallery items={image} onImageLoad={() => setShowImages(true)}/> 
         </div>

         ):(

         <div>
         <IonSpinner name="crescent" />
         </div>
        )}
      );
```

**Example given from package website**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ImageGallery from '../src/ImageGallery';

const PREFIX_URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/master/static/';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showIndex: false,
      showBullets: true,
      infinite: true,
      showThumbnails: true,
      showFullscreenButton: true,
      showGalleryFullscreenButton: true,
      showPlayButton: true,
      showGalleryPlayButton: true,
      showNav: true,
      isRTL: false,
      slideDuration: 450,
      slideInterval: 2000,
      slideOnThumbnailOver: false,
      thumbnailPosition: 'bottom',
      showVideo: {},
    };

    this.images = [
      {
        thumbnail: `${PREFIX_URL}4v.jpg`,
        original: `${PREFIX_URL}4v.jpg`,
        embedUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/4pSzhZ76GdM?autoplay=1&showinfo=0',
        description: 'Render custom slides within the gallery',
        renderItem: this._renderVideo.bind(this)
      },
      {
        original: `${PREFIX_URL}image_set_default.jpg`,
        thumbnail: `${PREFIX_URL}image_set_thumb.jpg`,
        imageSet: [
          {
            srcSet: `${PREFIX_URL}image_set_cropped.jpg`,
            media : '(max-width: 1280px)',
          },
          {
            srcSet: `${PREFIX_URL}image_set_default.jpg`,
            media : '(min-width: 1280px)',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        original: `${PREFIX_URL}1.jpg`,
        thumbnail: `${PREFIX_URL}1t.jpg`,
        originalClass: 'featured-slide',
        thumbnailClass: 'featured-thumb',
        description: 'Custom class for slides & thumbnails'
      },
    ].concat(this._getStaticImages());
  }

  _onImageLoad(event) {
    console.debug('loaded image', event.target.src);
  }

 render() {
    return (

      <section className='app'>
        <ImageGallery
          ref={i => this._imageGallery = i}
          items={this.images}
          onImageLoad={this._onImageLoad}
        />
      </section>
     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: what version of the library are you using? it seems like its an issue and fixed in `1.0.6` https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery/issues/480

Comment: @JeeMok currently using "react-image-gallery": "^1.0.7"

Comment: am I writing a callback correctly?

Comment: yeah from the example given it is correct. Does the example work for you? if not maybe create an issue on the GitHub as it is a valid bug. If the example works then maybe something wrong with your code, it'd be helpful to create a code sandbox so we can help to debug more efficiently